# How to click on and off submenu's using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I'm fairly new to javascript and web development in general. I'm currently trying to get my submenu's in my sidebar navigation area to pop up in response to an onclick event. I can open up my submenu's individually with some redundant javascript because i couldn't figure out how to do it with a loop (if that's even the best way). But even when I get this far I can't figure out the best way to close them up. Here is my HTML I'm using for my sidebar navigation

```
                   <ul id="sidebarNavUl">

                       <li class="sidebarLi">Main Topic:
                           <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Topic</a></li>
                           </ul> 
                       </li>

                       <li class="sidebarLi">Main Topic:
                           <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Topic</a></li>
                           </ul> 
                       </li>

                      <li class="sidebarLi">Main Topic:
                           <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Topic</a></li>
                           </ul> 
                       </li>

                   </ul>

               </nav>
```

As well as my CSS:

```
.sidebarLi ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 9000em;

}

.sidebarLi ul li a {
    color: #003354;
}

.sidebarLi ul li a:hover {
    color: #003354;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #edf3f6;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Notice I'm trying to start with my submenu's in absolute position and with my javascript I plan on inserting an inline style to bring them back to static position, because each topic is stacked on top of one another and I want them to expand when clicked on (since in absolute position they are not apart of normal document flow). I also have them moved to the right 9000 em's instead of hiding them to keep them visible for screen readers. So if someone could help me write good javascript code to bring the submenu's in and out when clicked upon it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

And in case you were wondering this was the javascript I was trying to write:

```
var mainSidebarLi = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebarLi");


mainSidebarLi[0].onclick = function () {

   mainSidebarLi[0].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.position = "static";
   mainSidebarLi[0].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.right = "0";

};

var mainSidebarLi = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebarLi");


mainSidebarLi[1].onclick = function () {

   mainSidebarLi[1].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.position = "static";
   mainSidebarLi[1].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.right = "0";

};
```

so that process would repeat till I got all elements in the li array.

Comment: Show your js codes please.

Comment: like this? click the second item  https://jsfiddle.net/aesya0g6/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer from another thread, if you want to use a tag in an li tag:

```
$('.expandingNav').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('ul').parent('nav.sidebar').length) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
            $(this).children('.hidden').slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        } else {
            $(this).children('.hidden').slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
        }
    }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t3w2Lbc/)

Comment: Okay thank you this seemed like it would work as well. Great response.

Comment: If it do help you, could you vote up this answer? or mark this is the correct answer if you think it is:)

Comment: Well I can't vote anything up yet as I don't have enough reputation apparently lol.

Comment: It's ok, try to answer more questions:)

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to go about it.  One simple way is to use jQuery toggleClass.  Add an active class to the ul tag and toggle that class on click event.

add this CSS style:

```
.sidebarLi ul.active {
position:relative;
left: 0;
```

}

add this jQuery:

```
$('#sidebarNavUl li').click(function() {
$(this).children('ul').toggleClass('active');
});
```

If you are new to adding JQuery - just add this right before your `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#sidebarNavUl li').click(function() {
$(this).children('ul').toggleClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! you are a life saver. worked like a charm. And ya I'm not too up to date with jquery yet. But it looks like I need to be. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to do this in javascript? Or would it be too complicated?